# How can I extract player information from Riot/ubisoft/steam/epic games accounts?

Tags: cross-platform, game-development

I want to make an app for gamers that uses statistics from the games they play. I want to link Riot/ubisoft/steam/epic games/ account to my app and use the user's game data (with permission of-course). Is there a way to access that information? I was not able to find much on my own. Steam has web apis that might be able to get that information but I don't understand how much information I can get from there as well.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use one of their internal APIs. Ubisoft uses its own demux API. There are several examples on GitHub on how to do that. In my case ,I am grabbing data from tracker.gg and Ubisoft.  Here's a repo for my API Server .
https://github.com/alexanderthegreat96/dth-division2-api